# Using a get function vs making a member variable public

Tags: c++, coding-style

What is the preferred C++ style, using a `get` and `set` function to get and set the value of a member variable, or just making the member variable public?

```
class MyClass
{
public:    
    std::string getValue();
    std::string setValue();
private:    
    std::string value; 
};
```

versus

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    std::string value;
};
```

The second one looks cleaner and I don't really see any advantage to the first one, other than getting you a bit more money if you get paid by lines of code.

Comment: The first one doesn't allow modifications.

Comment: The advantage of the first approach is that it doesn't expose the (mutable) implementation and private state of the object.

Comment: Well I could also include a `std::string setValue();` function if I want to make changes. I should have clarified that.

Comment: This decision is entirely about considering the future usage of your code. Will you change your interface in the future?

Comment: You have to ask what the class is abstracting if it provides a getter and setter.

Comment: If you don't see any advantage to the first one, don't use it in your own projects. Just note that many programers, including myself, have seen advantages in information hiding, and many authors have written about them. See for example [some results](https://www.google.es/search?q=software+benefits+of+information+hiding). Note that for mere aggregations of data with no abstraction associated to them, structs are traditionally used instead of classes C++. This is because their members are public by default.

Comment: Neither is good. Instead of making getters and setters, you should think about your business model and write your methods accordingly. With `get()` and `set()`, you'll end up with a lot of code like `setA(getA()+1)` spreading in your codebase.

Comment: @cassiorenan

So what alternatives do you suggest? In a case where I'll have code like `setA(getA()+1)` I just make the variable public, and in cases where I won't have a lot of code like that use `get` and `set`?

Comment: The alternative is to think. Think about the operations the object should have available and expose methods that do them. If you have an attribute in a class that needs to be completely exposed without any restrictions, it probably doesn't belong there. In case you'll need to use the code `setA(getA+1)` often(as an example), it is much better to simply expose the method incA(). That way you keep track of the only possible ways other objects could be affecting your class' state.

Comment: @cassiorenan My question was just if I have a variable that is going to need `get` and `set` functions, would it be better to make it a public member variable or just use the `get` and `set` functions. It seemed pointless and it would avoid cases like `setA(getA+1)`. Telling me to think is very constructive, but I'm asking this question because when I thought about it I wasn't sure what the proper way to do it was, and I even arrived at the wrong answer myself.

Comment: You're assuming the only two options are to use getters and setters, or making the attribute public. I'm just here to tell this isn't the case. You're asking if any of the two options are the "proper" way to do it, when most good articles say that none of them is, as I'm trying to clarify here for you. I'm trying to help you, here.
Using a rough example, is like you're asking: "Should I glue my shoelaces or sew them together?"

Comment: @cassiorenan Those are the two options I'm concerned about. I know that functions exist, my question was not about functions in general, it was if I have `get` and `set` is it better to just make the variable public to eliminate them or use the functions. I know i can write a function to increment my variables. I know I can write a function to change and use the variables in other ways. That isn't part of my question. I'm asking specifically about `set` and `get`.

Comment: The real issue is what is the probability that a future change will ever be made to the affected members, and if that change is made, would having get and set functions eliminate having to go through all of the code anyway, because the change goes beyond what a get or set function can encapsulate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > I don't really see any advantage to the first one, other than getting you a bit more money if you get paid by lines of code.

By this reasoning, the second approach might give you more money, factoring in maintenance cost.

Imagine, one day you would change `value` to be computed from other members. Having a getter makes it easy to add this behaviour without affecting the codebase.

The fact that there is a `string` value stored in each instance should be an implementation detail, not part of the publicly visible API (at least so in theory: without inheritance, the fact that the member exists is visible to any user). It is annoying to have to write boilerplate getters and setters, but in a long-term view it pays off.

Oftentimes though, classes that have too many setter and getter pairs have other design flaws and generally too much mutable state. Also, in C++ if a class with thousands of getter/setter pairs only holds state and defines no behaviour at all, it should rather be a `struct`.

Comment: But changing the implementation to calculate `value` on the fly would render the setter (which is already part of the interface) useless.

Comment: That's true - maybe the setter has never been used and can be more safely removed. Edited though.

Comment: @Alex To be clear though, when you say "classes that have too many setter and getter pairs have other design flaws," you don't mean to imply that using getters and setters is a design flaw itself, correct?

Comment: Exactly. - setters/getters itself is fine, but I find that classes that have too many of them often do too much at the same time. I personally like the pattern of capturing immutable state in objects (i.e. pass some state at object construction and hold it constant during the entire lifetime). In this case, there is much more getters than setters. YMMV though.

Answer (score 4):

Its not good practice to "show" object's guts to the world. Probably later you can want to change class implementation or even make your **value** not to be `std::string`.

As project grows, many things can change, and surely, you can add the `getValue` later, but in this case you are deprecating old "API" and creating a new, this can cause some problems with updating and so on.

Also, making **public** member allows users to read/modify this member, without notifying the class itself. This can create "bad design" problems.

Comment: `or even make your value not to be std::string` - how using access function can help in this case?

Comment: @Gluttton a getter can convert type from internal type to any another.

Answer (score 1):

A public class member is against encapsulation, which is one of the OO principles.

The most common convention is not to use the words get and set, only the variable name. We just let the compiler decide if it is set or get by the presence of the argument or its absence.

The member variable should start with a prefix 'm_'.

Other option is to start the function name with a capital letter and the variable with a regular..

This convention used by many open source libraries like ImageMagick and more.

Your class should be as follows:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void value(const std::string& v){
       m_value=v;
     }
    const std::string& value()const {
        return m_value;
     }
private:
    std::string m_value;
};
```